# What is the point in showing that $u\cdot v=u \cdot v_u$ in linear algebra when talking about the dot product?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

I am currently taking a course in linear algebra and in my linear algebra book at the chapter about scalar product / dot product it says

"Assume that $u=AB$ and $v=AC$. We now have that $|AC|cos(\theta)=|AD|$ and therefore $u\cdot v=|AB||AC|cos(\theta)=|AB||AD|$".

The figure that illustrates this is a line $AB$ that is visibly longer than a line $AC$. The line $AC$ going above the line $AB$ at an angle of what looks like about 35 degrees. Then there is a dotted line from the end of $AC$ straight down, creating a triangle at point $D$ which is between the points $A$ and $B$.

**What is the point of showing that $u\cdot v = u \cdot v_u$? This is clearly $v=v_u$.**

Comment: Presumably $v_u$ is meant to be the vector $\overrightarrow{AD}$, which is not the same as $v$. It is the component of $v$ in the direction of $u$.

Comment: You **just** gave an example where $v = AC$ and $v_u=AD$ are different, while $u\cdot v = u \cdot v_u$.  Why then do you think "This is clearly $v = v_u$"? (btw, as a general rule, I think it wise to avoid "clearly" in math, as it's either redundant or wrong)

Comment: Perhaps you're confused by the last line; $uv = |AB||AC|\cos\theta = |AB||AD|$ does *not* mean that $u = |AB|$ or $v = |AC|\cos\theta$ or that $v = |AD|$. It just says that the value of the expression on the right is the same as the value of the expression on the left. Note that $u$ and $v$ are *vectors*; $AB$ (the directed segment) is not the same as $|AB|$ (its length, which is just a number).

Comment: @almagest, yes $v_u$ is the vector $AD$. And as Klaas van Aarsen said, it is about projection. Brian Moehring, you are very much correct about $v \neq v_u$. I see now that I cannot simply remove the $u$. Also thank you Filip Milovanovic for pointing out how the equation is written so that I could get another perspective. I approached this from a completely wrong way. Thanks to your comment I managed to understand my erros and understand the material. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, when you have
$$
x\cdot y=x\cdot z
$$
where $x,y,z$ are three vectors (say in the Euclidean space),
it does *not* follow that $y=z$.

This is because $x\cdot w=0$ does not imply "$x=0$ or $w=0$".

Comment: Yes, I see now simplifying is not the same here as it is in previous algebra courses. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @linker: you are welcome!